# How to disabled options method on ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, math, request, cors

I want to get JSON data using an AJAX request on a remote API URL. However I am getting a a 'preflight method (OPTIONS) not allowed the on remote server and a `405 Method Not Allowed` response. I want to make an AJAX request without the preflight. Remote server allows only the `POST` method.

This is the jQuery code I use for the request

```
$(document).on('change', '#form-samples select[name=api]', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var APIUrl = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-url');
    var APIKey = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-key');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: APIUrl,
        dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': APIKey
        }
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });        
});
```

Comment: A preflight request is required when sending an AJAX request from JS to a third party domain. If the response is the 'method not allowed' error it sounds like the URL you're calling does not support CORS requests, and so you cannot use JS to do what you require. You would need to make the request server-side instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Umm. I understood. Well, how to CORS request with Ajax? CORS according to the rules. Which settings I need to edit on code?

Comment: You can't. CORS needs to be set on the API. If you have no control over the response the API sends then there is nothing you can other than work around the problem. Your options are to send a grovelling email to the API owners to ask them to enable CORS (which will not be fast - assuming they even do it which is unlikely) or to make the request server side and proxy your JS request to your own server.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Okay, I understood. I think so too. Thanks your responses.